# ostringstream issues

Tags: c++, printf, stringstream

when I use ostringstream, the only value that i get is : COM1
I have an application, which sends data. 
I am using the code as :

```
std::ostringstream values;
values << someStruct.someValues;
...
...
std::string data
data << values.str();
```

But when I run this, all I get is an output saying COM1. My application is a DLL file.

But when I do this method below, I get the correct values

```
char *data;
char values[20];
sprintf(values, "%d",someStruct.someValue);
strcat(data,values);
```

But I don't want to use the above method as I have many variables that I need to fetch from the program. So someone please help.

Comment: Post your *whole* code, it's impossible to say what's going on from just those snippets.

Comment: Also, your second code is broken; you can't use `strcat` with the uninitialized pointer `data`.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::string data;
data << values.str();
```

`std::string` is not a *stream*. It can't take `operator<<`. I'm surprised this code even compiles, but it almost certainly doesn't do something useful. What you want is this:

```
std::string data = values.str();
```